# Работа с Enum

Tags: asp.net, c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, mvc

Всем привет! Есть класс запись:

```
 public class Record
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    Required]
    public RecSectionEn Rec_SectionEn { get; set; }
}
```

перечисление:

```
    public enum RecSectionEn
{
    Политика = 1,
    Криминал = 2,
    Общество = 3,
    Интервью = 4      
}
```

для записи в БД цифирного значения секции я делаю:  recordBD.Section = (int)recordBL.Rec_SectionEn;

а как наоборот? Я с БД получил айдишку секции (цифри) и как ее передать на перечисление чтобы получить текстовое значение перечисления?

так ошибка:
    record.Rec_SectionEn = recDB.Section;

Comment: @Lifeactt перечисления не содержат тектовых значений - это отдельный тип. Если вам нужно конвертировать int в RecSectionEn, то все очень просто: 

    RecSectionEn rse = (RecSectionEn)yourInt;

Comment: спасибо большое,это обратное как с recordBD.Section = (int)recordBL.Rec_SectionEn;   что то не додумался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int valueInt = (int) RecSectionEn.Политика; // из enum в int
RecSectionEn valueEnum = (RecSectionEn) valueInt; // из int в enum

// Проверка доступности значения перечисления
RecSectionEn valueEnum = (int) 7777;
bool isDefined = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(RecSectionEn), valueEnum)

string valueString = RecSectionEn.Политика.ToString(); // из enum в string
RecSectionEn valueEnum;
bool canParse = Enum.TryParse(valueString, out valueEnum); // из string в enum
```